# Error in promise

Tags: angular, promise, rxjs, observable

I get the following error on `(this.data.getFacility(person.val1)`:

> Argument of type '{ "val3": 3; "val4": 4; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SubscribableOrPromise'.
>   Type '{ "val3": 3; "val4": 4; }' is not assignable to type 'PromiseLike'.
>      Property 'then' is missing in type '{ "val3": 3; "val4": 4; }'.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Data } from './data';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/observable/forkJoin';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()

export class UsersService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private data: Data) { }

  getData(arg): Observable<any> {
    return this.data.getPerson(arg)
      .flatMap((person: any) => Observable.forkJoin(this.data.getFacility(person.val1), this.data.getExposure(person.val2)))
      .map(([facility, exposure]) => facility.val3 * exposure.val5)
  }
}
```

The data service:

```
@Injectable()
export class Data {

    [x: string]: any;

    "person": [{
        "response": {
            "val1": 1,
            "val2": 2
        }
    }]
    "facility": [
        { "val1": 1 }, {
            "response": {
                "val3": 3,
                "val4": 4
            }
        }]
    "exposure": [
        { "val2": 2 }, {
            "response": {
                "val5": 5
            }
        }]

    constructor() { }

    public createPerson(arg) {
        this.person.push(arg)
        return this.person[0].response
    }
    public getFacility(val: Number) {
        this.facility.find(val1 => val1 === val1);
        return this.facility[1].response;
    }
    public getExposure(val: Number) {
        this.exposure.find(val2 => val2 === val2)
        return this.exposure[1].response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Should `([facility, exposure]) ` be `( facility, exposure) `?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data class return values instead of `Observable`. So it break your Observable stream.

To make your example work you need to import `Observable.of` in your class and use it like that (for rxjs6) :

```
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';

....

public getFacility(val: Number) {
    this.facility.find(val1 => val1 === val1);
    return of(this.facility[1].response);
}

public getExposure(val: Number) {
    this.exposure.find(val2 => val2 === val2)
    return of(this.exposure[1].response);
}
```

Or you can do that in your `UsersService`

```
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
....
getData(arg): Observable<any> {
    return this.data.getPerson(arg)
      .flatMap(
         (person: any) => Observable.forkJoin(
             of(this.data.getFacility(person.val1)),
             of(this.data.getExposure(person.val2))
          )
      )
      .map(([facility, exposure]) => facility.val3 * exposure.val5)
  }
```

Comment: it did not help.

Comment: Did you do the change in the Data class of in the UsersService. Did the error message stay the same ?